# Implementation of ConcurrentHashMap for One writer and more reader Threads in Java 8

Tags: multithreading, java-8, multiprocessing, threadpool

I have one concurrentHashMap where my one thread is continuously writing into this map and simultaneously more than 300 threads are reading values from this map.

Question :

1. In this multi threading scenario, is concurrentHashMap data structure is best one? If not then which one is more faster and will give better performance ?
2. To achieve this scenario, is there any better way like any design pattern.
3. Is it good idea to run these count of threads in system?
4. Is there any other way of declaration of consurrentHashMap so that I will achieve best performance.

Example : We can declare map with different parameters as follows. Currently I am using last option.

```
1.    Map<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>(initialCapacity, loadFactor, concurrencyLevel);
2.    Map<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
3.    Map<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
```

NOTE :

1. Size of map is equals to reading threads count. So if 300 threads reading from my map then size of map is 300 ( contains 300 key value pair values ).
2. 64 bit operating system with 32 GB RAM.

Comment: Why you are having 300 threads ? Even through you've 300 threads the threading will be again based on core of your system. IMO having some queue instead of these many threads will make more sense. As in bottomline 300 threads will never execute in parallel.

Comment: What is IMO? and then what will you suggest how should I achieve this scenario?

Comment: Not enough information to make such statements. For what you posted, the `ConcurrentHashMap` will work fine.